# Get String value from lambda DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda func that gets values from my DynamoDB table. The `String` values are printed  to my cloud watch logs but look like this  `{'S': 'Random String here'}` . How can I just get the string by itself. I understand that the `S` represents the attribute value for string https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html .
Lambda Code:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    e = event['Records'][0]
    message = e['dynamodb']['NewImage']['latestMessage']
    print(message) # This prints {'S': 'Random message here'}
```

How can I get the string without the `{'S': ' '}`

Comment: What about: `print(message['S'])`?

Comment: @Marcin This solution worked and is simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Boto DynamoDB Serializer/Deserializer to convert between DynamoDB and Python Objects.

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
deserializer = boto3.dynamodb.types.TypeDeserializer()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    e = event['Records'][0]
    message = e['dynamodb']['NewImage']
    deserialized = {k: deserializer.deserialize(v) for k,v in message.items()}
    print(deserialized) # This will print {'latestMessage': 'Random message here'}
```